# Field Permissions disabled on Profile Object Settings in Salesforce

Tags: permissions, salesforce, field, profile, user-permissions

I have a user profile in Salesforce which I'd like to be unable to edit some fields. Unfortunately in the Field Permissions section of the Profile Object Settings those fields appear as disabled (grayed out) but checked. Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're trying to edit one of the standard profiles that ships with salesforce. This isn't allowed. Clone the profile, edit the new profile as needed, then assign users to the new profile.

Comment: Jeremy thank you for your reposponse. In fact I cloned the standard user profile and after that I'm trying to accomplish these changes with no effect. I set the custom object permission for that profile for reading, and on the fields I have both standard fields like recrodtype and custom fields that are already selected as Read and Edit while disabled and can't find a way to uncheck them.